# if statement inside for loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Not working

```
     int sum = 0;
          for (int index = 0; index < ratpop; index++) {


// verify whether population falls within blast radius
             if (xcord[index + 1] - xcord[index] <= str
                   || ycord[index + 1] - ycord[index] <= str) 

{
                // if it does sum population of both points
                sum += pop[index] + pop[index + 1];
             }
          }
          // prints out sum and the cordinates are not correct have to figure out
          // later
          System.out.println(xcord[1] + " " + ycord[0] + " " + sum);
       }
    }
```

I have to array lists one of x cordinates and one of y cordinates my logic for this statement is that if x cordinate or y cordinate is less than variable str then sum if not dont but it doesnt do that it sums it up regardless. This is my original question but without all the extra stuff that might have deterred others from giving it a shot, thanks in advance to all the enthusiasts that make this site great and I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Posting a homework assignment and asking SO people to debug your code is considered very bad form here, which explains the downvotes.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for posting guidelines.

Comment: Homework? Well at least `index+ 1` will give an arrayOutOfBoundsException for index=ratpop-1. I'm pretty sure, that's not what you're talking about though.

Comment: You may find it useful to use a Logger to output information at various stages, and possibly to use an IDE to step through the code. Ultimately it has to be you, not us, who understands the logic of the program

Comment: yea it is not homework, this is something I am doing to gain more experience with java. The people that gave me down votes didn't understand what I wrote because I clearly stated at the end of my description that all I was looking for was help with the if statement within the for loop (very specific). Maybe it is my fault for posting so much information, but I just wanted to put everything in perspective for the person that was going to take the time to look at it. I did not just want a debug.  I apologize if my intentions seemed what they were not.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you are trying to access an index beyond the arrays bounds...

```
   for (int index = 0; index < ratpop - 1; index++) {
```

This will let you access [index+1] without getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException